# strange border in .NET report viewer

Tags: reporting-services, report, border, viewer, .net

I'm new to SSRS reports. I have a problem with report viewer.
I have one table. One column in table row is number and another column is subreport.
Only first row shows subreport borders correctly. Border in subreport in other rows (2nd, 3rd etc)
are strange. Some borders are shown and some not. Borders are OK on subreport table and that is fine,
but they are not shown  correctly on main report.

How can I solve this problem? Is this related with width and height of columns ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Try giving borders to the sub reports. If that doesnt work, try giving border to the cells in the table and check.

PS: Would be helpful if you could share a snapshot. Even I encountered a few such problems earlier!